# Fire onmouseover event when element is disabled

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, dom-events, onmouseover

I have some controls that I need to disable when users don't have edit privileges, but are sometimes not wide enough to show the entire text of the selected option element.  In which case I've added a tool tip with ASP.NET and the following code

```vb
ddl.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title")
```

This works when the control is enabled, but doesn't work when it is disabled.

The following alert will not fire when a mouse is over the select element:

```html
<select disabled="disabled" onmouseover="alert('hi');">
    <option>Disabled</option>
</select>
```

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/CbEPj/).

**Q**: *Can I fire the `onmouseover` event for controls that are `disabled`?*

Comment: Disabled button counter in Fiddle is firing for me Chrome 93 and Firefox 91.  Here's with alert (works in Firefox 91 but not Chrome 93): http://jsfiddle.net/7hqL2f1a/1/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Disabled elements do not fire events, e.g. users cannot hover or click them to trigger a popover (or tooltip). You can however wrap the disabled element with a `DIV` and listen to the event fired on that element instead.

Comment: could you please demonstrate

Comment: It appears that if the disabled element takes up 100% of the div, even this won't work

Comment: Do this and use "mouseenter" instead of "mouseover" and it will work.

Comment: Trouble is you lose the HTML 'not-allowed' cursor snf the pointer cursor once the button is enabled

Comment: As a comment: The [W3C HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#concept-fe-disabled) states, that `click` events are disabled. Vendors treat other events differently. Firefox, for example, seems to trigger some events like mouseEnter.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**: Please see [nathan william's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113937/fire-onmouseover-event-when-element-is-disabled/18114718?noredirect=1#comment72953737_18114718) for some serious limitations to this approach.  I've updated the fiddle to illustrate the problem areas more clearly.

---

Expanding on what [@Diodeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12579/diodeus) said, you can use **jQuery** to automatically create the `div` container for you and wrap it around any disabled elements.

1. Use the [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector to find all disabled elements.
2. Then call the [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method with a function callback
3. You can use *`this`* to refer to the current element in the set.
4. Then use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get the `onmouseover` value from the parent element and apply the same value to the new div.

```js
$(':disabled').wrap(function() {
    return '<div onmouseover="' + $(this).attr('onmouseover') + '" />';
});
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/CbEPj/)

Comment: Should be noted that there's still a dead zone over the disabled element itself.  If the wrapper has block style, then the effect will be erratic; if it has inline style, then the mouse may never transit any part of it to trigger the effect.  A z-index overlay element would behave more consistently, but would require inserting a sibling element with absolute positioning relative to the wrapper.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old post, but hopefully this answer will clarify how `@Diodeus` answer can be implemented!

Disabled elements do not fire events, e.g. users cannot hover or click them to trigger a popover (or tooltip). As a workaround, you can however wrap a `<DIV>` or `<span>` around the disabled element and listen to the event fired on that element instead.

NOTE! Using `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` in the wrapper `<DIV>` will not work as expected in Chrome (v69). But will however work in IE. Which is why I recommend users to use `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` instead, which is working great both in IE and in Chrome.

```html
   <select disabled="disabled" onmouseover="alert('hi');">
    <option>Disabled</option>
  </select>

  <div onmouseenter="alert('hi');">
    <select disabled="disabled" onmouseover="alert('hi');">
      <option>Disabled with wrapper</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

I've put together a JS fiddle with some examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dr4co/tg6134ju/

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. In the latest version of Chrome, `onmouseenter` did work as a replacement for `onmouseover` with `disabled` children but `onmouseleave` did not work as a replacement for `onmouseout`. Due to the `onmouseleave` issue, I still had to add a `::before` pseudo-element to the wrapper positioned on top of the `disabled` child in order to get `onmouseover` or `onmouseleave` to fire.

Answer (score 4):

For [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_pointerenter_event), you can use the `pointerenter` and `pointerleave` events instead. These fire even if the HTML Element is `disabled`.

Comment: This is right answer for disabled element to fire the event.

Comment: True! But before the year 2018, both Safari and Firefox did not have support for `pointerenter` and `pointerleave`. Back then it was better to use [mouseenter](https://caniuse.com/?search=mouseenter%20) or [mouseleave](https://caniuse.com/?search=mouseleave) =)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you add a title on the target element?
title looks like the same as tool tip.
And title works on disabled elements.

when you set the value of your select, also set title:

```
element.value=value;
element.title = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Justin, that's one way to go (which I think I might have ultimately gone with) - the problem is that there are a lot of selects that are conditionally disabled.  I needed the mouseover so the title would update appropriately when it *wasn't* disabled.  But seeding it with the correct title to start covers both cases.

Comment: To Kylemit, then you can add condition for it:  if(element.classList.contains("addTitle15")){  // add title

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but in chrome you can set css property pointer-events to all and it should allow for events. I haven't checked in other browsers.

```
button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

Edit:

Actually I think setting the property to auto is sufficient. As @KyleMit commented, support it's pretty good.

I just used this in project where I needed to disable an button until some validation rules where met, but I also needed to trigger the validation on hover over the button. So adding the pointer-events did the trick. I think it's the easiest way get over the problem stated in the OP.

Comment: This does not work at all for me, whether I use `all` or `auto`.

Answer (score -1):

there are two solutions for this

```
<Tooltip title="Tooltip" placement="bottom">
          <div>
            <IconButton disabled>
              <Done />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Tooltip>
```

or this one if you dont want miss the view

```
<Tooltip title="Tooltip" placement="bottom">
  <IconButton component="div" disabled>
    <Done />
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

[reference](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8416)